# How to decrement a for loop in JavaScript based upon a number that a user enters into a prompt?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, prompt, decrement

I want the loop to count down starting with the user's input number all the way down to 0. For example, if the user puts in 10, it will count down from 10 to 0. I think I'm close but need a little help.

```js
var userNum = Number(window.prompt("Enter number of your choice starting from 1"));
var i;
for (i = 0; i < userNum; i--) {
    window.console.log(userNum[i]);
}
```

Comment: `for (i = userNum; i >= 0; i--) { console.log(i); }`

Comment: What do you mean by _"to 0"_? Including `0`?

Answer (score 2):

You should make the loop start at `userNum` and end at 0:

```js
const userNum = Number(window.prompt("Enter number of your choice starting from 1"));
for (let i = userNum; i>=0 ; i--) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Also, if you decrement here, use `>=` instead of `<`. `userNum[i]` doesn't work, it's a number not an iterable, Array-like struct.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm just learning the fundamentals of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to use :

```js
const userNum = Number(window.prompt("Enter number of your choice starting from 1"));

for(let x=1+userNum; x-->0;){
  console.log('x',x);
}
```